# ngOnInit not getting called when navigating to a page through button click but called when navigating directly to it in browser

Tags: constructor, initialization, angular7, ionic4, ngoninit

I am having a problem in creating an ionic v4 app (actually migrating an old Ionic v1, Angular 1 app) wherein when I load a url directly in the browser the ngOnInit methods get called along with the constructors but when I navigate to that url through a button on another page then the objects are created (I see logs from constructors being called), html for the pages/components is displayed, but the ngOnInit for the page and component is not called.

In one part of my app I have a page with some common buttons and then some children components that get rendered in its router-outlet when one of the buttons in the page is clicked

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>create-join-root</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid fixed>
        ion-cols for buttons here. Depending on the button click different component path renders different html in router-outlet
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

The route path for this section of the app for this basepage in the basepage.module.ts is setup as such

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CreateJoinRootPage,
    children: [
      {path: 'createGroup', component: CreateGroupComponent},
      {path: 'createOrg', component: CreateOrgComponent},
      {path: 'joinGrpOrg', component: JoinGrpOrgComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

When I go to localhost:8200/basepage/createGroup the basepage and CreateGroupComponent constructors and ngOnit functions get called which initializes things as expected. However, when I go to an intermediate page in the App and then click on a button to go to the same url using

```
this.router.navigate(['/basepage/createGroup']);
```

The constructors of basePage and CreateGroupComponent get called, the html of basePage and CreateGroupComponent are rendered properly but the ngOnInit for basePage and CreateGroupComponent are not called.

I am missing something fundamental here. Look forward to your thoughts and feedback on how to make sure the page and the component get initialized when the user navigates there through a button click.

I am using Ionic 4 with Angular 7.2.2

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Comment: Usually in Ionic 4, if the page was visited at least once it won't be disposed of - it will be kept in the DOM and memory at least some time, so I think that is happening... You can try executing the code you need to execute every time in ionViewDidEnter or ionViewWillEnter

Comment: Thank you @Monomachus. In this case when I click on a button on a page which calls a function which calls route.navigate('/basepage/creategroup') to go to the desired page, that's the only time that page is being visited in this path. I have logs on console in the constructor and ngOnInit to show when they get triggered and I don't see ngOnInit ever being called when I go through the button click.

However when I go directly to that page i.e. /basepage/creategroup in the browser then the constructors and ngOnit both get triggered as I see in the console logs.